# C - Repeat prompt until valid user input

Tags: c, loops

How to I make this loop repeat until the user enters either -2, -1, 0, or a positive number?

```
int main(int argc, char argv[]) {
    char n[3];
    char line[LINESIZE];
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    sscanf(line, "%s", n);
    do {
        if (n == 0) {
            printf("DISPLAYING ALL RECORDS.\n");
        append();
        } else if (n > 0) {
            printf("MODIFYING RECORD %s", n);
        } else if (n < 0) {
            printf("APPENDING RECORD %s", n);
        }  else if (n == -2) {
            printf("QUITTING.");
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    } while (1);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int n;
    char line[LINESIZE];
    do
    {        fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    }while(sscanf(line, "%d", n) != 1 || n < -2);`

Answer (score 0):

use a do/while loop:

```
do
{
   // code to be looped (ask the input value)
} while (n < -2)

// here you can check the values as in your code
```

Comment: This doesn't work for some reason it just prints the modifying record.

Comment: I think your do while (1) loop is wrong, it results in a never ending loop. If you want to continuously enter input and act to it, place the do while (1) loop around the complete body, and add the while loop from my answer around the input lines only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get that what you exactly want to do with your code but

```
while(n<(-2))
{
      // Your code
      // again take n as an input
}
```

Should do the required task of your question.

Comment: This doesn't keep looping it just prints modifying record then ends

Comment: Okay so basically what you want is the loop to repeat without taking any input unless user gives some value greater than equal to -2

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `kbhit()` and `getch()` to take input while loop is running. The `kbhit` function checks for the presence of a keystroke during that moment and the `getch` function is used to retrieve the data of that keystroke, if `kbhit` gets a keystroke it returns a nonzero value if not it returns 0